# CSS selector for elements without text siblings

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to find a CSS selector that can help me distinguish between the `<var>` tags in these 2 different usages:

```
<p><var>Foo</var></p>
```

And

```
<p>Some text <var>Foo</var> and more text</p>
```

Basically if a var has a sibling that is a text node I need to style it differently. Suggestions?

Comment: No, I don't need to support IE6.

Comment: There is no such CSS selector alone that can do this. You will have to detect such elements with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, sorry. Check out that discussion: http://forum.userstyles.org/comments.php?DiscussionID=6 or the official W3C pages http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ where you can see that even CSS3 will not support this. The only way CSS even considers the DOM text nodes is the :empty pseudo class selecting elements that are empty, i.e. do not have children neither text nodes.