# remove multiple extra break tags with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I have this HTML with multiple `<br>` tags.

```
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
TITLE
<br>
<br>
foo bar
<br>
foo bar
...
```

I want to keep only single and double breaks at most (new line and new paragraph) and I want to ignore all extra `<br>`. So having maximum 2 `<br>` one after another. So,

```
<br><br><br><br><br>TITLE<br><br>foo bar<br>foo bar<br><br><br>foo bar
```

would become

```
<br><br>TITLE<br><br>foo bar<br>foo bar<br><br>foo bar
```

How can I do this with CSS?

I would like to select all `<br>` elements who have at least 2 immediate previous `<br>` siblings

EDIT: for a bit more of context, the HTML is on an external web site, I try to improve the reading with firefox/stylish, so only with CSS

Answer (score 7):

By using `:nth-child` selector you can achieve it easily.

**CSS:**

```
br:nth-child(3n + 3) { display: none; }​
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/4yDkS/)

Comment: Deleted my answer. Your solution is more generic compared to adding a long list of `br + br + .....`

Comment: But `br+br+br` works in IE8 (still over 20% market share http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8#Adoption) and below, where `nth-child` doesn't

Comment: It does not really work. It turns 3 br into 2, but it does not turn 6 br into 2. If I understand it right, what you propose removes every third br. Also it will remove a single br if it happens that it is a 3-nth from the start, which we don't want.

Answer (score 3):

While `<br>` tags [can't be styled in any other way in most browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899252/can-you-target-br-with-css), you can hide them:

```
br+br+br {display: none}​ /* (Also works in IEs 7+8) */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/Wxf3D/1/ (thanks @A.K)

The problem with this is that with the markup `<br><br><br>hello<br>` it will also match the final `<br>` because it doesn't count text nodes as siblings. You could fix this by updating the markup to:

```
<br><br><br><br><br>
<p>TITLE</p>
<br><br>
<p>foo bar</p>
<br>
<p>foo bar</p>
```

Of course you can also remove these elements with jQuery if you want:

```
<script>
    jQuery("br+br+br").remove();
</script>
```

(I'm afraid I lost patience with trying to work out a JavaScript-only solution)

Comment: But you can hide it by using `display:none`, See my answer.

Comment: You can do it with `css` by using `nth-child` selectors, as did in my answer.

Comment: Yes I saw that, I thought I'd offer an alternative selector syntax if that's okay. Also, sibling selectors (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2) are supported in more browsers than nth-child selectors (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Comment: I thought this would work, but it does not seem to work on your Fiddle, as it removes also single or double br, which we want to keep.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Sibling selector doesn't notice text nodes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374950/css-selector-for-elements-without-text-siblings). You could fix it by adding `<p>`s around the text, or using JavaScript, but if not then this versions of the selector is not feasible. Apologies.